# Obtain the Stripe fee from Payment Intent

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to pull out the Stripe processing fees from the PaymentIntent - but I cannot seem to find it. Is there another call I need to make on the API?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this when [retrieving](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/retrieve) the Payment Intent by [expanding](https://site-admin.stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) certain fields:

```js
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.retrieve('pi_xxx', {
  expand: ['charges.data.balance_transaction'],
});
```

Your `paymentIntent` constant will then include a [`balance_transaction`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/object) hash on the related Charge object that will include details of the Stripe processing fees.

Comment: See also Stripe docs for that https://stripe.com/docs/expand/use-cases#stripe-fee-for-payment and a little more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65146439/936284

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which gives a json with all the Stripe fees details :

```
async function bankingFeesFun(paymentIntentId) {
  const balance = await balanceTransaction(paymentIntentId)
  return {
    amount: balance.amount,
    fee: balance.fee,
    net: balance.net,
    currency: balance.currency,
    fee_details: balance.fee_details
  }
}

async function balanceTransaction(paymentIntentId) {
  return await stripe.balanceTransactions.retrieve((await chargeFun(stripe, paymentIntentId)).balance_transaction)
}

async function charge(paymentIntentId) {
  return await stripe.charges.list({
    payment_intent: paymentIntentId
  }).then((res) => {
    return res.data[0]
  })
}
```